# jQuery Multiple Selector with split

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, split

I have this row with two `<td>`'s with classes **messageROW** and **titleROW** following a checkbox with the ID of '**activecd**'. I'm trying to change the bg color of both **messageROW** and **titleROW** (the whole row) when the checkbox is toggled but instead titleROW only changes colors.

Any suggestions?

```
$('[id^=activecd]').change(function(){
    $('.messageROW,.titleROW'+$(this).prop('id').split('activecd')[1]).closest('td').toggleClass('colorcode', this);
});
```

**HTML**:

> ```
> <tr>
>      <td class="messageROW"></td>
>      <td class="titleROW"></td>
>      <td><input id="activecd"></td>
> </tr>
> ```

Comment: If you're trying to change the "whole row", then just use `$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('colorcode')`

Comment: I've added in the HTML... nothing fancy. I've tried using .closest('tr') but it didn't work. It works for td though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, albeit untested:

```
$('[id^=activecd]').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('colorcode', this.checked);
});
```

This listens for the `change` event on the specified element(s), finds the closest `tr` element and adds the `colorcode` class if the checkbox is checked, and removes the class if not.

Comment: Doesn't work for 'tr' however it works fine for 'td' (the cell where the checkbox is contained in).

Comment: Really? That suggests you need to modify your css to style the element(s) appropriately, such as: `tr.colorcode, tr.colorcode td { /* styles here */ }` to see it working inspect the DOM, there's no reason this shouldn't work (in that the class should be added to the `tr`).

Comment: changing my CSS from ".colorcode" to "tr.colorcode td" fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery `$().add(selector)`, `$().toggleClass("bgOn")` with css

```
<style>
.bgOn {background:rgb(255,230,230)} // any css to toggle.
</style>
```

Not clear question, I think.

```
<button onclick="someFunction(this)">Toggle color</button>

function someFunction(this){
  var $this=$(this);
  $this.parent().find(".messageROW,.titleROW").toggleClass("bgOn");
  // or
  $this.parent().parent().find("tr>td:first-child, tr>td:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("bgOn");
}
```

might help you.